# android 4.4.2 VFY: invalid switch target 22 (-> 0x18) at 0x2[0]

Tags: android, bytecode, dalvik, opcode

I insert new bytecode in class dex. 
Bytecode is packed-switch(x2bx00xFFxFFxFFxFF).

I'm success code injection.

It works well under 4.3 version. 
But It doesn't work 4.4.2

This is the stack trace.

```
07-08 20:54:54.504: W/dalvikvm(1165): VFY: invalid switch target 22 (-> 0x18) at 0x2[0]  
07-08 20:54:54.504: W/dalvikvm(1165): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x2b at 0x0002  
07-08 20:54:54.504: W/dalvikvm(1165): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/hello_test/MainActivity;.<init> ()V  
07-08 20:54:54.504: W/dalvikvm(1165): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/hello_test/MainActivity;  
07-08 20:54:54.504: W/dalvikvm(1165): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/hello_test/MainActivity;)  
07-08 20:54:54.504: D/AndroidRuntime(1165): Shutting down VM
07-08 20:54:54.514: W/dalvikvm(1165): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2aacba8)  
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165): Process: com.example.hello_test, PID: 1165
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165): java.lang.VerifyError: com/example/hello_test/MainActivity
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)  
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)  
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)  
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)  
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)  
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)  
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-08 20:54:54.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Most likely, it's saying the bytecode is invalid because the bytecode is invalid.

Comment: if the bytecode is invalid, not working under 4.3 version. but it works well

Comment: Just because it worked in an old version of Android doesn't mean it's valid. They probably just made the verifier stricter.

Comment: @Antimony This is a pretty fundamental check.  As noted in my answer you can find the same code in the verifier back in Android 1.6.  I'm pretty sure it was present in 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You're failing verification because the address you're trying to branch to is not an instruction.

Very little has changed in the Dalvik runtime since mid-2011, so it's unlikely that this is a change in the verification behavior.  There have been a few changes to "dx", so it's possible that the method's bytecode is being generated differently, and your code-injector isn't working correctly with this output.

The first thing to do is get a disassembly of the DEX file (using dexdump or smali) and see what lives at instruction offset 0x18.

FWIW, the verification code is `checkSwitchTargets()`.  You can see it in the [kitkat sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/analysis/DexVerify.cpp), and if you want to get historical it's `dvmCheckSwitchTargets()` back in [donut](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/donut-release/vm/analysis/VerifySubs.c).